# Inserting a char at specific location in R character string

Tags: r

I have a R string like this

```
a <- "(hi I am (learning R) )"
```

I want to add a character "x" in above string and make it like

```
"(hi I am (learning R)x )"
```

How can I do that using R efficiently?

Edit : Adding 1 more information:
       Assume that the pattern can change for starting character string but last 2 bracket in the end will remain same all the time and I have to insert x between them all the time.

Comment: Are you going to do this for a number of strings? What is their pattern? Adding `x` to one example string is trivial but it might not be applicable to your actual data

Comment: sub("R)", "R)x", a)

Comment: What Phil said, and then either ycw's comment or a combination of `paste` and `substr` or also `sprintf("(hi I am (learning R)%s )","x")`

Comment: I just added above some more details..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub`, capture the unique pattern that you want to insert after and then use back reference to add `x`:

```
sub("(R\\))", "\\1x", a)
# [1] "(hi I am (learning R)x )"
```

---

Update on inserting character between two brackets at the end of the string, the simplest would be match a pattern and replace it with your desired one:

```
sub("\\) \\)$", "\\)x \\)", a)
# [1] "(hi I am (learning R)x )"
```

Comment: Adding 1 more information: Assume that the pattern can change for starting character string but last 2 bracket in the end will remain same all the time and I have to insert x between them all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your response but as added in detail that I am not aware of earlier string pattern. I only know last 2 bracket pattern. Is there some way I can use this info that I have to insert x in second last position only (after 2nd last bracket)

Comment: I think the second option would do, What's wrong with it?